# Single - row subQuery returns more that one row in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I am trying to write a Query in Oracle which will return multiple row ,but with this Query i am getting "Single row subquery returns more that one row", I have tried to use IN operations in the place of "=" operator but i can not make it , This is my Query

```
 Update Quote_line_part_quantity 
 SET 
 resale_am =(
select target_resale 
FROM Quote_line_part_quantity 
where quote_id=100218906
)
WHERE 
 quote_id=100218906
 AND quote_line_no IN(
 SELECT 
 quote_line_no
 FROM 
 Quote_Line
 WHERE 
quote_id IN 100218906
AND quote_line_no=(1)
AND Quote_line_status_cd IN('R','A')
);
```

I am confused why this is giving this error again and again .Please help

Comment: You need to correlate the subquery you're updating with to the rows being updated. A field can only be updated with a single value, not multiple values. However, what is it that means you can't just do `update ... set resale_am = target_resale where ...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely problem is here:

```
set resale_am = (select target_resale 
                 from Quote_line_part_quantity 
                 where quote_id = 100218906
                )
```

The best way to solve this is unclear, but adding `and rownum = 1` will fix your immediate problem.

Comment: You may think it saved your day, but all it did was clear the error.  There is zero guarantee you are actually getting the desired result.  As earlier stated, you were trying to update a single row value with a result that returned multiple values.  Now, you have to decide which of those multiple values is correct.  There is no inherent order in a result set, so simply adding 'rownum = 1' will return exactly one *random* row.

Comment: @EdStevens . . . The returned value is **not** "random".  It is indeterminate.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - you prodded me to do a quick read on 'randmon' vs. 'indeterminant'.  Whichever way one wishes to classify this issue, the end result is the same ... the OP using simply 'where rownum = 1' to limit the results to a single value is doing nothing to control *which* row provides the value to be used .. so does not know if it selected the *correct* row for the operation.